# Unable to append HTML elements to a div dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to add html elements to a div dynamically but i am unable to do so at all. I replaced `var s='<a href='+hrf+'><img src='+hrf+'alt="Tulips"></a>';` with `var s = '<button>click</button>';` just to check if there is anything wrong with the string i am appending and still no luck.

**Script in Head**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

       window.onload = GetRecords();     

            function GetRecords() {      
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Gallery.aspx/insertimg",                   
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }

        function OnSuccess(response) {

            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var count = parseInt(xml.find("imgtable").length);
            var imageTable = xml.find("imgtable");           

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {               
              var hrf = imageTable.find("ImageUrl").eq(i).text();                            
             var s='<a href='+hrf+'><img src='+hrf+'alt="Tulips"></a>';
              $('.html5gallery').append(s);               

            }           
        }

</script>
```

**Body**

```
<body>
    <div style="display:none; flex-align:center" class="html5gallery" data-skin="horizontal" data-width="480" data-height="272">
   </div>
</body>
```

**XML**

```
<NewDataSet>
  <imgtable>
    <PhotoId>4</PhotoId>
    <Name>Photo4</Name>
    <ImageUrl>photoalbum/DSCN5798.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <AlbumId>2</AlbumId>
    <Date>2013-04-03T17:03:02+05:30</Date>
  </imgtable>
  <imgtable>
    <PhotoId>5</PhotoId>
    <Name>Photo5</Name>
    <ImageUrl>photoalbum/DSCN5799.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <AlbumId>2</AlbumId>
    <Date>2013-04-03T17:03:13+05:30</Date>
  </imgtable>
  <imgtable>
    <PhotoId>6</PhotoId>
    <Name>Photo6</Name>
    <ImageUrl>photoalbum/DSCN5800.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <AlbumId>2</AlbumId>
    <Date>2013-04-03T17:03:13+05:30</Date>
  </imgtable>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="gallery.aspx?albumid=2" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="5WcBQJLHmIC4X/c0os4kFsh4tUCcOP93YgL5uIChec+tPgpqBaWkU5jZaSmvwM4MMGjdK8G9LD+/HV8GvINckwe5HGGXFcY7BgEpkFo0CEM=" />
</div>     
    <div style="display:none; flex-align:center" class="html5gallery" data-skin="horizontal" data-width="480" data-height="272"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: i can't see you appending anything in div

Comment: i am pretty sure your error is in this line `imageTable.find("ImageUrl").eq(i).text();  `  .. what actaully ImageUrl is ?? id ,class ...what??

Comment: @TusharGupta i am appending check again, there was a mistake in formatting code on SO because of which line with append  was not visible in the question here.

Comment: @Arbaaz okay go it ...

Comment: @bipen ImageUrl is a url for image which i am adding to href and src

Comment: i mean to say is it an id or class of the element that you are trying to find ?? since your are using it in `find()`

Comment: @bipen he's reading XML thus it is node name probably

Comment: ahhh .. ok .. got it ...:)

Comment: @Arbaaz can you show XML structure that is returned?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in `window.onload = GetRecords();` - it should be `window.onload = GetRecords;`.

Also in the ajax request you are saying the response is `json` but in the success callback it is processed as `XML`

But in jQuery you can use the dom ready also to achieve the same

```
jQuery(GetRecords)
```

When you use `window.onload = GetRecords();` the `GetRecords` executed and the value returned is assigned as the `onload` handler, which is not what is needed. What is needed is `GetRecords` to be called once the window is loaded for that you need to pass the function reference to `window.onload` using `window.onload = GetRecords;`

Try

```
jQuery(GetRecords)

function GetRecords() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "Gallery.aspx/insertimg",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : OnSuccess,
        failure : function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error : function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var count = parseInt(xml.find("imgtable").length);
    var imageTable = xml.find("imgtable");

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var hrf = imageTable.find("ImageUrl").eq(i).text();
        var s = '<a href=' + hrf + '><img src=' + hrf + 'alt="Tulips"></a>';
        $('.html5gallery').append(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: in jquery: `$(window).on('load',GetRecords)`

Comment: @roasted yes... sorry

Comment: I changed `window.onload = GetRecords();` to `jQuery(GetRecords)`
still no luck! I even changed `var s = '<a href=' + hrf + '><img src=' + hrf + 'alt="Tulips"></a>';` to `'<button>click</button>'` to check if there is problem with hrf , still not working.

Comment: and i have checked the count using `alert(count)` and its not 0 or null its 3.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) `

Comment: @Arbaaz that means your request is failing... look into that first

Comment: @ArunPJohny How is it failing if OP says that alert(count) == 3 ?

Comment: @pawlakppp i dont think there is any problem with retriving data from xml because i am not even able to append simple hardcoded `<button>hi</button>` to div

Comment: @Arbaaz but it could have failed before on first line `var hrf = imageTable.find("ImageUrl").eq(i).text();`

Comment: @pawlakppp can you make this piece of script work ..  http://jsfiddle.net/YKE5P/  ?

Comment: @pawlakppp
Ok i am able to load the images BUT they seem to be outside the div and in rendered source they do not even appear. I mean the img tags do not even appear on rendered code but images are visible outside the div.

Comment: @Arbaaz How do you check rendered code ? 'View page source' ?

Comment: @pawlakppp yes thats how.
If i hardcode `<a href="PhotoAlbum/DSCN5795.jpg"><img src="PhotoAlbum/DSCN5795.jpg" alt="Swan on Lake"/></a>` in div then it displays images just fine as it should i.e within the div. But When i am adding those images dynamically the images are outside div and not resized as they should be

Comment: @pawlakppp Should i use load() somewhere ??

Comment: @Arbaaz, first thing: install firebug (if you use firefox), 'View page source' does not display added dynamic content, firebug shows. Maybe problem is that you missed '/' on the end of img tag in your dynamic content

Comment: @Arbaaz, and no, load() is not suitable here